# How to print keys and multiples values associated with the keys in the Python list with dict values?

Tags: python, list, key

this is list in python with dictionary values

```
 [{abc.txt': ['abc', 'F']}, {'xyz.txt': ['xyz', 'F']}].
```

How to print keys and value in the list? Eg: `key"abc.txt"` and `values(0)=xyz` and `values(1)=F`

Comment: iterate through list elements and print `item.keys()` and `item.values()` ?

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your question to be a bit more clear? What is your full expected output?

Comment: for this value {abc.txt': ['abc', 'F']}. I want key as 'abc.txt' and values 1 as 'abc' and 2 as 'F'. can you please help me out?

Comment: What do you mean "you want"? In what format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want but you weren't very clear.

You just need some nested for loops: iterate through the list, then the dictionaries and then the values list:

```
lst = [{'abc.txt': ['abc', 'F']}, {'xyz.txt': ['xyz', 'F']}]

for item in lst:
   for key, values in item.items():
       print('key: {!r}'.format(key))
       for index, value in enumerate(values):
           print('values[{}]: {!r}'.format(index, value))
```

outputs:

```
key: 'abc.txt'
values[0]: 'abc'
values[1]: 'F'
key: 'xyz.txt'
values[0]: 'xyz'
values[1]: 'F'
```

Comment: Thank you FHTMitchell !! You guy is absolutely genius. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

That depends how you want to iterate. Let's see-

```
x = [{'abc.txt': ['abc', 'F']}, {'xyz.txt': ['xyz', 'F']}]

for i in x: #iterate over list of dicts
    for k, v in x.iteritems(): #iterate over dict
        print k, v
        # prints abc.txt(k) ['abc', 'F'](v)
```

Another method is -

```
for i in x:
    print i.keys(), i.values()
```

For python3, change `x.iteritems():` to `x.items():` and prints to `print(k, v)`